# Why is my image not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

At http://blajeny.com I have:

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event_object)
    {
    spark(event_object.pageX, event_object.pageY);
    });

function spark(x, y)
    {
    console.log('Spark called.');
    var image_object = new Image();
    image_object.onLoad = function()
        {
        image_object.style.position = 'absolute';
        image_object.style.zIndex = 1;
        image_object.style.top = y;
        image_object.style.left = x;
        }
    image_object.src = '/img/spark.png';
    }
```

The intended effect, at this stage, is to load an image at the X and Y where the user clicked. (I want to do other things as well, like animate it, but right now I'm trying to get the image to show up where the user clicked.)

The javaScript console shows that the handler is being called, however I am not seeing what I expect, a hazy blue circle immediately below and to the right of the point where the mouse was clicked.

What can/should I do differently so it loads a fresh image below and to the right of the clicked coordinates?

Thanks,

Comment: @all, thanks for the responses. I have my immediate goal now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `onLoad` should be `onload`

```
var image_object = document.createElement('img');
image_object.onload = function() { // Note the small onload
    // your code
}

// Also, append the image_object to DOM
document.body.appendChild(image_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never append the image to the DOM, that's why you can't see it.

You can do

```
document.body.appendChild(image_object);
```

You must also replace `onLoad` by `onload` and specify the `top` and `left` position with an unit :

```
image_object.onload = function()  {
    image_object.style.position = 'absolute';
    image_object.style.zIndex = 1;
    image_object.style.top = '100px';
    image_object.style.left = '100px';
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5qAk9/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you appending the image to DOM that's probably why you're not seeing it

```
$('body').append($(image_object));
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, first create an element with the "img" tag, assign the src value to it, and append it to the current div (in this case its the body), like so

```
var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
imgTag.src = '/img/spark.png';
document.body.appendChild(imgTag);
```

Hope this helps.